# how to select all grid items in foreach loop in telerik asp

Tags: asp.net, foreach, telerik-grid

This code shows me null value. In fact I have 4 rows in the grid count, but the problem is that it's showing me null value.

```
// loops through each row in RadGrid
foreach (GridDataItem row in RadGrid.MasterTableView.Items) 
{
    Table = Table + row["Columns_Name"].Text.ToString() + " ";
    Table = Table + row["My_data_type"].Text.ToString() + " ";
    Table = Table + row["Col_Primary_Key"].Text.ToString() + " ";
    Table = Table + row["Null_NotNull"].Text.ToString() + "\n,";
}
```

Comment: What is `Table` and what is `Text`?

Comment: What is showing you null value? I can see several points where a null reference exception could happen.

Comment: string Table = "CREATE TABLE dbo." + txtTable_Name_Master.Text +  "( \n";

Comment: I append all data into string table

Answer (score 0):

```
 string value = item.Cells[0].Text; //take the value from the first columns of each row
```

Comment: Code answers are good, but it would be even better if you added an explaination!